# Need to display event title before event time (fullcalendar)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have events that contain both the event title and event time. However, I need to have 'fc-event-title' show up first in the event, before 'fc-event-time'. Right now it's the opposite. How would I go about switching this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please make it more clear that your talking about DOM elements called fc-event-title and fc-event-time.

Comment: i think you will have to edit the main jscript in the skeleton() function and swap it in there- might sound hard work but will save hacking it with sytles or jquery.

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for the tip. I was able to solve the problem by editing fullcalendar.js, and switcing the order of fc-event-time and fc-event-title on lines 3665-3670.

Comment: Well done! I added an answer so that other people will know how to do this. If you dont mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User @ppumkin suggested that I edit the core javascript (fullcalendar.js), which proved to be the solution. I took the following item on line 3665:

```
(!event.allDay && seg.isStart ?
"<span class='fc-event-time'>" +
htmlEscape(formatDates(event.start, event.end, opt('timeFormat'))) +
"</span>"
:'') +
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" +
```

And replaced it with the following:

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" +    
(!event.allDay && seg.isStart ?
"<span class='fc-event-time'>" +
htmlEscape(formatDates(event.start, event.end, opt('timeFormat'))) +
"</span>"
:'') +
```

Basically, I just put the 'fc-event-title' span before 'fc-event-time'.

Comment: Yea - i thought mine was wrong :D  Good work- i think a few people will use this one! :)

Comment: Exactly the help I needed.  Saved me a ton of time searching for this in the fullcalendar.js

Comment: For maintability it would be better to do this via the provided eventRender callback. Otherwise you're going to have to re-do this work every time you want to update your fullCalendar version, even just for a bug fix release

Answer (score 2):

I am adding my answer so that it might help someone who don't want to modify the javascript library (fullcalendar.js)

Here I am swaping the HTML of "fc-title" and "fc-time" at "eventRender" function. 
**eventRender** is triggered while an event is being rendered. And in "eventRender" function we can modify the calendar DOM.

This code worked for me.

Referece for eventRender: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
              element.find('.fc-title').each(function () {
              $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('.fc-time'));
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How far appart can the title be from the time?

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/866a825b53ac22eebfbbedc6ec6961c2.png))</sub>

If you don't mind it in the right hand corner you can just float the time right.

as all the times have a class called fc-event-time `<span class="fc-event-time">5p</span>`

```
.fc-grid .fc-event-time {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I have the title and time split vertically already, [like so](http://imgur.com/Rnu5W). So I'm not sure if a float would be the solution.

Comment: @Jeremy can you show what you have? A screenshot would be good also.

Comment: Hi chobo2, [this is what an event looks like](http://i.imgur.com/Rnu5W.gif). I've solved this issue by editing the core Javascript. See my comment on the original question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeremy- Thats good you where able to figure it out. Just remember if you ever update you will have to remember to readd those changes.