# Need to display event title before event time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In the below image, event was displated as "7a Birthday Party".
How to display event name before event time like  "Birthday Party 7a"?

[image]

Modified JS Code in fullcalendar.js at 14475 - 14495

```
return '<a class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"' +
            (eventDef.url ?
                ' href="' + util_1.htmlEscape(eventDef.url) + '"' :
                '') +
            (skinCss ?
                ' style="' + skinCss + '"' :
                '') +
            '>' +
            '<div class="fc-content">' +
            (this.dayGrid.isRTL ?
                titleHtml + ' ' + timeHtml : // put a natural space in between
                titleHtml + ' ' + timeHtml //
            ) +
            '</div>' +
            (isResizableFromStart ?
                '<div class="fc-resizer fc-start-resizer" />' :
                '') +
            (isResizableFromEnd ?
                '<div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer" />' :
                '') +
            '</a>';
```

Comment: What have you researched or tried? Here's a clue: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to display event title before event time (fullcalendar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943443/need-to-display-event-title-before-event-time-fullcalendar)

Comment: @ADyson, i modified fullcalendar.js (i used this in header instead of mini) by moving timeText after eventDef.title in between 13819 and 13833. This change did nothing. Then i changed line number 14486 to titleHtml + ' ' + timeHtml. This change did not give me expected outcome. Then I posted this question to stackoverflow. I dont notice anything in eventRender that can help me with resolve this, it might be their but i dont no it yet.

Comment: @JainamShah, thanks you for point the post. I did modify js based on that post, but did not work. I only posted this because that post sees like way old and those line number are not same anymore. hope some one will provide the new line number

Comment: " I dont notice anything in eventRender that can help me with resolve this" well you can completely change the entire HTML of the event, you can do whatever you like. That documentation page says `element is a newly created jQuery element that will be used for rendering. It has already been populated with the correct time/title text.` ...but of course you can overwrite that with anything you want to, or you could simply extract those elements and reverse the order. You have total freedom. Using this is a better solution than modding fullcalendar.js, because you can still install upgrades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fullcalendar.js i modified line number 14486 to render the event name before time.

```
timeHtml + ' ' + titleHtml //Line 14486 Before modification

titleHtml + ' ' + timeHtml //Line 14486 After modification
```